# how to return a list of values for dictionary and populate them into a list?

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary

```
dctCourses = {1000:'Intro to IS',1505:'Fundamentals of Programming',1515:'Web Programming Overview',2550:'Visuals Basic I',2560:'Visual Basic II'}

lstCourseKeys = []

index5 = 0

for key in dctCourses:
    lstCourseKeys.append(key)
    index5 =index5 + 1

lstCourseKeys.sort()

index6 = 0

for item in lstCourseKeys:
    print(item)
    index6 = index6 + 1

lstCourseValues = []

index7 = 0

for value in dctCourses:
    lstCourseValues.append(value)
    index7 =index7 + 1

lstCourseValues.sort()

index8 = 0

for item in lstCourseValues:
    print(item)
    index8 = index8 + 1
```

I created a dictionary and need to create a list storing the keys and a list storing the values and have both list print back in a sorted list. when I run the code above I get this

```
1000
1505
1515
2550
2560
1000
1505
1515
2550
2560
```

it appears the list of keys works as expected but my values list seems to populate the keys and not the values. Am I missing something or do I need to change something?

Comment: As in the given answer: use `iteritems`. `for value in dctCourses` does not work this way as `value` is just a variable name. There is no difference to your previous loop. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, `keys`, you may want to use `dctCourses.iteritems()`:

```
for key,_ in dctCourses.iteritems():   #`_` ignores the values
    ...
```

and similarly with the `values`:

```
for value in dctCourses.values():      # only getting values
    ...
```

Output:

```
1000
1505
1515
2550
2560
Fundamentals of Programming
Intro to IS
Visual Basic II
Visuals Basic I
Web Programming Overview
```

Checking both are still lists:

```
print type(lstCourseKeys)
print type(lstCourseValues)
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also found that changing "for value in dctCourses:
    lstCourseValues.append(value)
    index7 =index7 + 1" to "for value in dctCourses:
 lstCourseValues.append(dctCourses.get(value))
 index7 =index7 + 1" worked as well, though I imagine it's a dirty way of doing it

Comment: Welcome. Sure I imagine there are many ways to accomplish it, I don't know what would be clean or dirty, whichever way gets the job done. Glad it helped :)